# adding global variable in colab cause indent error

Tags: python, global-variables, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to add a global variable to quicksort algorithm in colab. It works fine without the global variable 'r' but when I introduce it, I receive nonsense error of indention. but indention is correct. pls help.

````
    # Quicksort Sort
r=0
def partition(array, low, high):
  global r
  pivot = array[high]
    i = low - 1
    for j in range(low, high):
        if array[j] <= pivot:
            i = i + 1
            (array[i], array[j]) = (array[j], array[i])
      r=r+1
    (array[i + 1], array[high]) = (array[high], array[i + 1])
  r=r+1
    return i + 1

def quickSort(array, low, high):
    if low < high:
        pi = partition(array, low, high)
        quickSort(array, low, pi - 1)
        quickSort(array, pi + 1, high)


data = [7,1,3,2,4,5,6]
print("Unsorted Array")
print(data)
size = len(data)
quickSort(data, 0, size - 1)
print('Sorted Array in Ascending Order:')
print(data,r)

   ```
the error:
    ``` File "<tokenize>", line 11
    r=r+1
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
    ```
````

Comment: please attach the code snippet properly and/or share a screenshot as it's not possible to see the indentations in the format you shared.

Comment: trying but dont know how

Comment: select all the content and press `ctrl+k`

Comment: use ` symbol above tab on your keyboard, not ' (the quotation mark)

Comment: the `global r` in your code is clearly not indented right

Comment: yes i see it here but in colab it is right

Comment: thanks, my problem was I just copied the code and the indention wasn't correctly shown in colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation correction.

```
r=0
def partition(array, low, high):
    global r
    pivot=array[high]
    i=low-1
    for j in range(low, high):
        if array[j] <= pivot:
            i = i + 1
            (array[i], array[j]) = (array[j], array[i])
        r=r+1
    (array[i + 1], array[high]) = (array[high], array[i + 1])
    r=r+1
    return i + 1

def quickSort(array, low, high):
    if low < high:
        pi = partition(array, low, high)
        quickSort(array, low, pi - 1)
        quickSort(array, pi + 1, high)


data = [7,1,3,2,4,5,6]
print("Unsorted Array")
print(data)
size = len(data)
quickSort(data, 0, size - 1)
print('Sorted Array in Ascending Order:')
print(data,r)
```

**Output:**

```
Unsorted Array
[7, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
Sorted Array in Ascending Order:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 19
```